# SQL Server partition by gives duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following table:

```
Date     | ID | firstname 
---------+----+------------
20161128 | 1  | Adam      
20161128 | 2  | Steve     
20161128 | 2  | Steve     
20161128 | 3  | Aaron     
20161129 | 1  | Adam      
20161129 | 2  | Steve     
20161129 | 2  | Steve     
20161129 | 3  | Aaron
```

I want to get the first row by ID for one particular date.

So what I had was:

```
SELECT *    
FROM tableA   
WHERE Date = 20161128
```

this however, gives all records. So I used the partition over function:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    row_number() over(partition by ID order by Date desc) 
FROM tableA 
WHERE Date = 20161128
```

In this case, I get following result:

```
Date     | ID | firstname | rownum
---------+----+-----------+-------
20161129 | 1  | Adam      | 1
20161129 | 1  | Adam      | 2
20161129 | 2  | Steve     | 1
20161129 | 2  | Steve     | 2
20161129 | 2  | Steve     | 3
20161129 | 2  | Steve     | 4
20161129 | 2  | Steve     | 5
20161129 | 2  | Steve     | 6
20161129 | 3  | Aaron     | 1
20161129 | 3  | Aaron     | 2
```

As you can see, Most ID's appear 2 times. (ID 2 even appears 6 times). In other cases, I see a record appear 10 times even though it would only have one record if I used the first query.

Any idea why this happens and how this can be fixed? My guess would be the date/where clause, but I don't see how this can effect the result this much.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`TOP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `WHERE` clause if you want to filter the records:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.*,
             row_number() over(partition by ID order by Date desc) as seqnum
      FROM tableA a
      WHERE a.Date = '20161128'
    ) a
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This will return one row per date per id number.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace

```
SELECT *,

row_number() over(partition by ID order by Date desc)

FROM tableA

WHERE Date = 20161128
```

to

```
SELECT *  

FROM tableA

WHERE ID = (select min(ID) from tableA )
```

Answer (score 1):

This will only display the first instance.

```
Select * from
(SELECT *,
rownum=row_number() over(partition by PersonID_EXT order by SnapshotDate desc)
FROM tableA
WHERE Date = 20161128)x where rownum =1
```

Comment: be sure to alias that row_number column. You reference it as rownum but didn't alias it as such.

Comment: you placed rownum in the wrong place... it should be after the last closing parentheses `... desc) as rownum`

Comment: @HoneyBadger not where Khris has it originally (see his edit). It was `row_number() rownumber over(partition by PersonID_EXT order by SnapshotDate desc)`. His last edit made it acceptable.

Comment: @scsimon, removed comment

Comment: @HoneyBadger no worries at all mate.